# Migrate hundreds of databases to Azure elastic database pool

Tags: database, azure, migration

I'm aware of the various options in place for migrating a single database up to Azure. My problem is that these all only seem to cater for a single database at a time. However, I have a db per tenant model with over 2000 databases to migrate and not a lot of time to play with.

Can anyone point me in towards the best (ie fastest) way of doint this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we accomplished this with Powershell and the Azure API. Essentially batch creating bacpacs on the source server, uploading them to blob storage then importing them into Azure SQL server pools.

If I was facing the same challenge now I'd take a look at the Azure Database Migration Service - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/database-migration/

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this problem and am going down the route of using the Visual Studio data compare tool.

All my tenant databases have the same schema so I made an empty template database in Azure, and just use the `CREATE AS COPY` command to make a new one each time ready for receiving the migration.

Then I ask Visual Studio to compare the empty database with the live database and automatically insert the data for me.

Seems to be working well so far, there's very little manual steps needed and it doesn't involve using the Azure Portal, or blob storage or creating databases outside of the elastic pool which is great.  But the overall time will be slow to migrate data for all the databases.